# $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=cxe^{-x(x+y)}$ Find $f_x$. $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=cxe^{-x(x+y)}$$
I calculated $c$ to be $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$

$$f_x=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}xe^{-x^2}e^{-xy}dy$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}xe^{-x^2}\int_0^{\infty}e^{-xy}dy$$
$$=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}\int_0^{\infty}(-x)e^{-xy}dy$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2};x>0$$

did i do this right?
Anyways the problems comes in when i am evaluating $E(X)$ and $E(X^2)$

$$E(X)=\int_0^{\infty}x\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\times-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\infty}-2xe^{-x^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

I'm not sure if this is right?

$$E(X^2)=\int_0^{\infty}x^2\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}dx$$
ok i'm totaly stuck here.. I can't think of any distribution identities to use.. I thought of using normal but that just ends up a huge mess. How do i process?

Comment: I think your work is correct. You could do your last integral by parts: let $u=x$ and $dv=\dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-x^2}\;dx$.

Comment: @MickA I tried doing by parts but i don't know what the anti-derivative of $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Use substitution $x=u/\sqrt{2}$ to get it into the form of a standard Normal.

Comment: @ok i'll try that. i intitally though of $u^2=\frac{x^2}{2}$ but that is just messed up

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{hint}$

If you require a method of solving the last integral, then use differentiation under the integral sign.
$$
\int_a^b x^2\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}dx = -\partial_{\alpha}\int_a^b \mathrm{e}^{-\alpha x^2}dx
$$
where you evaluate the derivative w.r.t $\alpha$ at $\alpha=1$ and use the limits (you should see something you recognize)

Comment: I'm not exactly following this. what exactly are you doing?